# Why can't I connect to wireless?

Tags: wireless, networking

Originally it was just my home wifi. So I started using my [wireless "egg"](http://roaming.kt.com/renewal/eng/wibro/rental.asp) to connect to the Internet or my cell phone hotspot. Now I can't connect to those either. My home wireless doesn't even show up anymore as a wireless option (although it does on other devices), and for my egg and phone hotspot it just continually searches and searches without connecting.

```
iwconfig:
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

What sorts of things would you like to see to help me?

Thanks Ubuntu community!

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.

Comment: Here you go Wild Man: http://pastebin.com/mbwHqjjP

Comment: I should mention that I can now connect to wireless through other avenues at home - my egg and my phone hotspot - but those are hit and miss. My computer still cannot see my home wifi, which is visible on my phone, my wife's phone and her notebook.

Comment: it appears you have a bug in that driver, where did you install it from?

Comment: I don't recall for sure. My computer came factory installed with Ubuntu and the drivers on it. Should I contact Dell and tell them to give me a new driver for my wireless? How do I resolve it?

Comment: So I searched around and found this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1710562

Comment: And that made me think that you may want my lsusb and lspci: http://pastebin.com/CPdBKiEE

Comment: Then I found this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1569966. FYI, mine says on the back that it is a Dell 3421. NOT a 4010 like those instructions are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's update the driver and see if we can get it working. Download the driver from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/bcmwl-kernel-source) make sure to download the driver for your system, i386 for a 32bit system or amd64 for 64bit system.  Download it to your download folder then run:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
sudo modprobe -rv wl
sudo modprobe wl
```

Edit:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

(this will create or edit a configuration file that will override the default power management behavior) and enter the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

above exit0, then save gedit, close and reboot.

Comment: I got an "error while processing": http://pastebin.com/X5RDDKn6. I proceeded with the other two commands anyway, which just shut off and turned on my wireless connection.

Comment: By the way Mad Man, you rock. Thanks so much for all this great help.

Comment: Please do `sudo apt-get purge --remove bcmwl-kernel-source` then try again.

Comment: Strange. Nothing changed. http://pastebin.com/sbu4RsiR

Comment: By the way I need to write and read Korean so I installed those language packs. Relevant?

Comment: After you ran `sudo apt-get purge --remove bcmwl-kernel-source` did you run the commands in the answer above again? I do not see any information in pastebin from those commands.

Comment: I am going to add some commands to my answer to turn of power management please run them and report back. Did the download of the driver go okay?

Comment: Went through the entire set of directions again. Slight changes in the results - http://pastebin.com/gkN5NB9j

Comment: Can't seem to get the driver to upload steve@steve-Inspiron-3421:~$ -i ~/Downloads/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
-i: command not found
steve@steve-Inspiron-3421:~$ -i ~/Downloads/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
-i: command not found
steve@steve-Inspiron-3421:~$ 
The file is there for sure. That second one is copied out of the name of the file I downloaded.

Comment: SUCCESS!!! Not quite sure what the thing that put us over the top was, but I'm now online with our home WiFi. Wild Man, you really are the man.